# Z-index [Bootstrap 3]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I have the code below for a sidenav, how do i make it display 5 list items at a time so the user has to scroll to see more?

```
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation" style="float:left">
      <div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><strong>Select a subject</strong></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Maths</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Art and Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Drama</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Physics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Chemistry</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Biology</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home economics</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Physical Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Computing Science</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">French</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">German</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mandarin</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Religious Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Modern Studies</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Geography</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Creative computing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Craft, Design and Technology</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div><!--/.well -->
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->
```

Comment: I'd use a `div.sidebar-nav{ overflow-y: scroll; }` and setting it to a fixed height.

Comment: You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9z8M4/ ?

Comment: Yes exactly like this, is there any custom sliders that come with boostrap that look better than the default scroll bar?